# How to set multiple json attribute in single set statement in karate api?

Tags: karate

In Karate Api feature file, I  want to set multiple  Json attributes in single line, can we do that?

example:
I want set below details in single line

- set firstName = 'firstname' 
  And set lastName = 'lastname' 
  And set  age ='25'

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. But you can do this:

```
* def foo = {}
* eval foo.bar = 'bar'; foo.baz = 'baz'
```

But really, I strongly recommend you don't do this. Is this really the most important thing to worry about ? Focus on making your tests readable to other people.

I think you are missing that Karate is all about JSON, so you typically don't need to do all this. Just init a JSON directly:

```
* def foo = { bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz' }
```

Comment: Thanks you. Actually we have json payload file separately to send post request. And few attributes we need to set dynamically based on other API response. So we did in  multiple set statements. Now checking is there any way to set in single line.

Comment: @priyadarisini nope. maybe you can ask a magician for help